# unordered_set from std

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, unordered-set

I have to rewrite windows-code into crossplatform view. Here is the example:

```
std::unordered_set<Type>::iterator it = ...;
it._Ptr->_Myval->...
```

Everywere in code there is `_Ptr` member in iterator but I can't find it in docs. I think it works with visual studio (it's implementation of stl). Any ideas how to replace it? And what is `_Myval`?

---

UPD:

```
for(std::unordered_set<QuadTreeOccupant*>::iterator it = ...)
   it->aabb;

class QuadTreeOccupant
{
   public:
      AABB aabb;
};
```

And the error at line `it->aabb`:

> error: request for member ‘aabb’ in ‘*
>   it.std::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<_Value, __constant_iterators,
>   __cache>::operator-> with _Value = qdt::QuadTreeOccupant*, bool __constant_iterators = true, bool _*cache = false, std::*_detail::_Hashtable_iterator<_Value, __constant_iterators,
>   __cache>::pointer = qdt::QuadTreeOccupant* const*’, which is of non-class type ‘qdt::QuadTreeOccupant* const’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are implementation details of `unordered_map` specific to VC's implementation. You should just remove the reference to `_Ptr` and `_Myval` and use either of:

- `it->`
- `(*it).`

in place of `it._Ptr->_Myval.`

Comment: @Ockonal: `(*it)->aabb`, as the `hash_map` contains *pointers*, which need to be dereferenced too

Answer (score 1):

As for the update: the iterator is "like a pointer" to the element, so `*it` refers to the contained element; *but*, you can't access the members of your elements using `it->`, since your member element is a pointer, and thus an iterator is "like" a double pointer.

Long story short, you have to do:

```
(*it)->aabb;
```

since `*it` gives you a `QuadTreeOccupant*`, and you can then access its members via the `->` operator.

---edit---

too late...

Answer (score 0):

The `_Ptr` looks like an implementation detail which you shouldn't have access to (i.e. it should probably be `private) and you shouldn't use in any case: names starting with an underscore and followed by a capital letter are a no-go area for everybody except people explicitly invited in. These are just implementers of the C++ system (e.g. compiler and standard library writers).

You just want to use

```
it->...
(*it). ...
```

... to access the elements of the iterator.